# Split Time in android

Tags: java, android, time, split

In one of my `MySQL` table, it has a column with datatype `TIME`. So when it insert, I will get `01:49:00`. Is there a way to make it display `01:49` when it is retrieved ? Thanks.

```
  String timeOut = c.getString(Configs.TAG_TIME_OUT);
  String[] last1 = timeOut.split(":", 2);
  Log.e("D",last1[0]);
```

I want `01:49` , but it gives me `01`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its showing only hour value because you are using only that. After splitting the string it is converted into an array which contains items on based on the pattern string was split.

Here array `last1` has length of 3 because string `01:49:00` has three values separated by the pattern.

Do this

```
String time = last1[0] + ":" + last1[1];
Log.d("D", time);
```

Comment: What is `search`? Is it an adapter or `ArrayList`?

Comment: Adapter..I can pass time to listView ?

Comment: You will have to add this value to the adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 1):

It gives you `01` because you are displaying only the 0th index which has `01`, the 1st index would have `49` and the 2nd index would have `00`.

So if you want a string with `01:49`, concat the 0th and 1st index.